# Search tweets and filter by maximum number of replies

Tags: twitter, tweetdeck

I'm searching popular recent tweets with some keywords and I want to filter out the noisy ones (those with a lot of drama). Matching tweets with a lot of replies or by verified users tend to be political.

I'm currently using TweetDeck and I show tweets from all users, matching my keywords, with at least X likes and Y retweets. I'd like to **filter by a *maximum* number of replies**, but TweetDeck only offers to filter by *minimum* number of replies.

Is there a trick to do this on Twitter, or does some client/tool exist to do it?

The [filter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/overview.html), [standard search operators](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators) and [premium operators](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/premium-operators) don't even include the filtering options offered by a TweetDeck search.

In a TweetDeck search, a tweet comes with this sort of HTML blurb which contains the number of replies (see source):

> 21  Reply         99  Retweet        350   Like       More options

So I guess one could match the HTML: `<span class="... reply-count">21</span>`. I hope it's not the only way...

Comment: I've tried [Choqok](http://choqok.kde.org/) and [Turpial](https://turpial.org.ve/) but I couldn't find any such feature.

Comment: Didn't try all of those yet, some claim a "filtering" feature but no idea what is meant by that https://www.tecmint.com/best-linux-twitter-clients/